# On click save link to variable and redirect to differnet link

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage with many links on it. I want to add a script to work through out the whole page that when any link on the page is clicked on the page it will save that link to a variable and then redirect to to www.redirectlink.com

SO far I have

```
$('a').click(function(){
location.href='http://www.redirectlink.com';
return false;
});
```

Is this right and how would I make it save the original url in a variable that I can use later on on the www.redirectlink.com page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.location.href='http://www.redirectlink.com?ref='+this.href;
    return false;
});
```

You can now use `$_REQUEST['ref']` in the redirectlink to check the refferer.

Comment: Thanks and just to double check this would go in the header of my page?

Comment: You can put this into `<script></script>` tags in your header, but be sure to include jquery! Good luck with your project

Comment: @rsplak what is the means of use `e.preventDefault();` with `return false;`?

Comment: So my head would look like
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/
    sickbeard_public/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();document.location.href=
    'http://www.redirectlink.com?ref='+this.href;
    return false;
    }); </script>
    </head>
I can't get script markup to work :(

Comment: your `src` is not right give the real path relative to `htdocs`, `localhost` is not a path

Comment: Still not working.. So if the jquery is in the same folder as my index.php would it just be src="jquery.js" ?